# Android Room - How to perform VACUUM after performing massive table migration?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

We have performed a massive DB table migration.

```
public class Migration_22_23 extends Migration {
    public Migration_22_23() {
        super(22, 23);
    }

    // (1) Change `type` INTEGER to `type` INTEGER NOT NULL
    // (2) Change `reminder_type` INTEGER to `reminder_type` INTEGER NOT NULL
    // (3) Change `reminder_repeat` INTEGER to `reminder_repeat` INTEGER NOT NULL
    // (4) Change `reminder_day_of_week_bitwise` INTEGER to `reminder_day_of_week_bitwise` INTEGER NOT NULL
    // (5) Change `uuid` TEXT to `uuid` TEXT NOT NULL
    // (6) Change CREATE INDEX `index_plain_note_uuid` ON `plain_note` (`uuid`) to CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_plain_note_uuid` ON `plain_note` (`uuid`)
    // (7) Drop column `theme`
    // (8) Drop column `key`
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        ...

        // Reclaim disk space.
        database.execSQL("VACUUM");
    }
}
```

At the end of migration, we would like to perform one-time `VACUUM` to reclaim disk space.

However, we would get the following runtime error.

```
Cannot vacuum from within a transaction
```

Do you know any safe way for us, to vacuum the DB, so that we can reclaim disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the possible ways.

```
public abstract class MyRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public static MyRoomDatabase instance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (MyRoomDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        MyApplication.instance(),
                        MyRoomDatabase.class,
                        NAME
                    )
                        .addMigrations(new Migration_1_2())
                        ...
                        .addCallback(getCallback())
                        .build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback getCallback() {
        return new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onOpen(db);

                if (shouldVacuum()) {
                    try {
                        db.execSQL("VACUUM");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
                    }

                    resetShouldVacuum();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

`shouldVacuum` and `resetShouldVacuum` are referring to global static variables, which is being turned on in `Migration_1_2`